# how to get notified about signal connects and disconnects from slots with boost signals2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals2

I'm working with [`boost::signals2`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/signals2.html) and am looking for a way to get notified when signals are connected and disconnected. Is there a built in functionality or is it possible to implement this on top of it?

I had a glance at the implementation and think it cannot be done without changing the library itself. If this is correct, is there a known reason for why it's not possible or already implemented?

Comment: Why? Whole concept of having signals and slots is to be oblivious who and when is connected. Signals should be like a Stinger rocket "fire and forget". This sound like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: No there is no such functionality built-in.  I think its not in to a) keep it lightweight, and b) it is usually not needed (well actually never). Since you write the code that connects and disconnect the signals/slots it should be easy to add some callbacks there. Also I cannot even think about a use case where I would need notification of changes in registration that sounds a lot like an XY problem to me. (And I've been using events/signals/slot like mechanisms a lot).

Comment: Last side note, if you are in a multithreaded environment and you you add/remove connections at runtime (so after start of your system and before shutdown)... boost::signals2 is NOT threadsafe. It cannot handle subcription changes and calling of callbacks at the same time.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I've got some heavy computations which i can skip when there are no slots waiting for them. Atm i'm checking if any slots are connected on every loop which is ok but i know the pattern from other libraries and was wondering why people are not using it here.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think your thread safety claims are wrong. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77640618/85371 signals2 is remarkable in that respect

Comment: @sehe Boost signals 2 is not free of race conditions (and thus IMO not threadsafe enough). In an heavily multithreaded system these are just as deadly. E.g. no strict guarantee an object is no longer called after disconnect (because another thread is still using the copied callback list).  And yes I've seen those race conditions happen so it was out with boost::signals2. And we replaced with a custom implementation that will synchronize administration with calling of the slot. The only thing you can then not do is unsubscribe from a handler function, but there will be no race condition.

Comment: @PepijnKramer true, that's not "thread safety" though. It's just not avoiding races in your application domain. That's always application domain responsibility

Comment: @sehe I agree, but not everyone will make that distinction. I see lots of developers making the same assumption : if it is threadsafe then it will not have dataraces. So sometimes it is still worth mentioning this. (And that's why I used the term "threadsafe" loosely) ;)

Comment: Oh, but it *will* not have data races. It may still have application *race conditions*. Data races are UB by definition in the C++ abstract machine. Signal2's thread safety guarantees are remarkable.